# Microsoft Teams Channel / Amazon Lex integration

Tags: microsoft-teams, azure-bot-service, amazon-lex

I have a working Amazon Lex bot that I am trying to integrate into an MS Teams channel, such that a user can converse with the bot from within the MS Teams channel. I have created a simple echo bot in Azure and ca access it in MS Teams chat, and am now struggling to make any further progress - which I assume is connecting the Lex and Azure bots in some way (and probably more) ! The closest documentation I have found is https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/cleverer-chatbot-amazon-lex-microsoft-teams-wuming-zhang/ but I am finding it very difficult to follow. If someone can point me to clear instructions or provide them, that would be amazing and I would be forever in their debt. (PS. This is my first ever post - apologies if I have failed to observe any protocols - I hope that I learn fast). Thank you.

Comment: Could you please look at [Create a Bot for Microsoft Teams](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/bots/how-to/create-a-bot-for-teams), You can scope your bot for [channel & group chat conversation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/bots/how-to/conversations/channel-and-group-conversations?tabs=dotnet).